# ASP.NET Core AuthenticationHandler dependency injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Following [this article](http://geeklearning.io/how-to-migrate-your-authentication-middleware-to-asp-net-core-2-0/), I am trying to implement a custom `AuthenticationHandler`, but I got stuck on dependency injection.

I need to inject an `IRepository` instance into the `AuthenticationHandler` to provide a dbo connection (to check the credentials).

Code:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<CustomAuthenticationOptions>  
{
    // how to inject this?!
    private IRepository repository;

    public CustomAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) {
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // this is just a sample
        if (repository.users.Count(w => w.user_name == Request.Headers["user_name"] && w.password == Request.Headers["password"]) == 1) 
        { 
            return Task.FromResult(
                AuthenticateResult.Success(
                    new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(Options.Identity),
                        new AuthenticationProperties(),
                        this.Scheme.Name)));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(
            AuthenticateResult.Failed("...");
        );
    }
```

Do you have any hints?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/dependencyinjection

Comment: This is `authentication` rather than `authorization` I'm afraid @Fals.  Similar ballpark but not the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

Just add the repository dependency to the constructor, set the variable in the constructor body

```
public CustomAuthenticationHandler(
    IOptionsMonitor<CustomAuthenticationOptions> options,
    ILoggerFactory logger,
    UrlEncoder encoder,
    ISystemClock clock,
    IRepository repo)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) {
    repository = repo;
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution but the dependency is not getting resolved :(

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I tried Jack's solution and it works.

I have had a huge issue with dependency injection of Repository (with EF DataContext) into Middleware. When my Angular SPA loaded, it fired multiple parallel requests into API. I got randomly InvalidOperationExceptions, something like "db context cannot be used while being created"

Absolutely nothing has helped until I totally hopeless moved dependency injection from Middleware constructor into Invoke method:

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IRepository repository)
 {
     ...
```

But AuthenticationHandler seems to have a different flow. Works like a charm.